# How can I select a range of records from the middle of a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table '`users`' with structure -

`id int auto_increment primary key, 
name varchar(25), 
username varchar(25))`.

I have 20 records in it.
I want to fetch all records in the range 5-10. How can I do that in 'MYSQL'?

I tried solutions that I saw on many websites but they didn't work for me. They showed errors while executing query.
I tried this query too:

```
SELECT * FROM users offset 5 rows fetch next 5 rows only;
```

But it didn't work too. How can I achieve the desired result in 'MySql'?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5`

Comment: Or perhaps you want `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id BETWEEN 5 AND 10`?  It's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT  column_name(s) FROM table_name LIMIT from, number;
```

Where number specified no. of records to be returned and from specified location from which record fetching will start.

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5, 5;
```

Comment: Be careful to always specify a completely deterministic sort order when using `LIMIT`, else the results are indeterminate.

Comment: Thankyou sir. I'll take care. @eggyal